# How do I check if two specific programs exist on a system in an if conditional?

Tags: bash

I have the following in my .bashrc to print a funny looking message:

```
fortune | cowsay -W 65
```

I don't want this line to run if the computer doesn't have `fortune` or `cowsay` installed.

What's the best or simplest way to perform this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type` or `which` or `hash` to test if a command exists.

From all of them, `which` works only with executables, we'll skip it.

Try something on the line of

```
if type fortune &> /dev/null; then
    if type cowsay &> /dev/null; then
        fortune | cowsay -W 65
    fi
fi
```

Or, without `if`s:

```
type fortune &> /dev/null && type cowsay &> /dev/null && (fortune | cowsay -W 65)
```

Answer (score 1):

`type` is the tool for this. It is a Bash builtin. It is not obsolete as I once thought, that is `typeset`. You can check both with one command

```
if type fortune cowsay
then
  fortune | cowsay -W 65
fi
```

Also it splits output between STDOUT and STDERR, so you can suppress success messages

```
type fortune cowsay >/dev/null
# or failure messages
type fortune cowsay 2>/dev/null
# or both
type fortune cowsay &>/dev/null
```

[Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620)

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is not to get the error messages appear in case of not being installed, you can make it like this:

```
(fortune | cowsay -W 65) 2>/dev/null
```